# Python 3.2 script not working and/or importing tkinter when running from desktop

Tags: 12.04, gui, .desktop, python3

I'm really puzzled by this, but the answer is probably quite simple and just can't see it:

I have a series of python modules that work fine from within the python interpreter, but nothing happens when running from a GUI situation. I've tried creating a .desktop file, adding shebangs, changing permissions to 777 and renaming to `.pyw` for all the modules. A single test module works fine on its own, so I know that it's not a typo error.

If I click the main module `.pyw` file and click 'Run' from the system dialogue nothing happens at all. Similarly the `.py` file (and the `.desktop` via menu), nothing happens. Here is the start of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import tkinter as tk, imp, sys


root = tk.Tk()
msg = tk.messagebox
sdg = tk.simpledialog

import capitaliser_cfg as cfg, fileio as io
imp.reload(cfg) ; imp.reload(io) 

### GO AND GET COUNTY LIST ####
# Nb: attach to config for simplicity
cfg.counties = io.getfilelist("counties.txt", "London")

if not type(cfg.counties)==list:
    k = msg.showerror(cfg.version, cfg.counties)
    root.destroy()
    root.mainloop()

### GO AND GET DICTIONARY ####
cfg.tempdict = [[],[],[]]
cfg.spelldict = io.getdictionary("addressdict.txt","roda","Road")
if not type(cfg.spelldict)==dict:
    k = msg.showerror(cfg.version, cfg.spelldict)
    root.destroy()
    root.mainloop()


import thinbutton as tb, labelradio as lr, fieldblock as fb, bigbutton as bb 
import textblock as tx, padding as pd, widget_tools as wt
import capitaliser_mth as mth
import capitaliser_bnd as bnd


imp.reload(tb) ; imp.reload(lr) ; imp.reload(fb) ; imp.reload(bb)
imp.reload(tx) ; imp.reload(pd) ; imp.reload(wt) ;
imp.reload(mth)
imp.reload(bnd)
```

If I `put k = msg.showerror("xxxx","yyyy")` after the line `sdg = tk.simpledialog`, stil nothing happens which leads me to believe that *tkinter* is not loading for some reason.

Any ideas anyone ?

Comment: @ Corvus. Add the solution as a answer. So others can get benefit. When searching, Most people open the question only if it was marked as an answered question. (with Green icon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution kindly supplied on Stackoverflow board by Furas:

For Python 2 try:

```
import tkMessageBox
import tkSimpleDialog

msg = tkMessageBox
sdg = tkSimpleDialog
```

or simpler:

```
import tkMessageBox as msg
import tkSimpleDialog as sdk
```

For Python 3 try:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import simpledialog

msg = messagebox
sdg = simpledialog
```

or simpler:

```
from tkinter import messagebox as msg
from tkinter import simpledialog as sdg
```

**** I used the last 2 lines and it works perfectly now..